# How can I create a popup chat window like in facebook in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an asp.net core 2.0 MVC solution. Currently I have a chat implementation with its own view, and controller. This chat uses signalR to signal to the proper users and EntityFramework to store messages. And this website has a home page where are different informations.

What I wanted to do is that to move this chat view into a small "window" like in Facebook. So there is a website and my previously implemented view would render above the page.

I am really new in asp.net core and website development so I don't really know what technologies exist. Can you give me some opportunities, how can I solve this problem? Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Since you've implemented SignalR, I assume you're familiar with jquery? That's literally what you need. You just need to style that small window with css, and attach events there with jquery.

Comment: Also ajax to send messages

Comment: Its all about designing, With signalR you Push data from server to client side With Realtime Feature. It up to you how u render data coming from signalR Hub. Upon receive event call, you have to display little window with bottom 0; and append the data in this window.